# ViewOverlay equivalent for API 8

Tags: android, animation

So I have an issue where I need to animate a "button" that exists inside of `FrameLayout`.
Sadly, the bounds for that animation exceed the bounds of the `FrameLayout`.

As it currently stands, this means that the animation gets "cropped" by the bounds of the `FrameLayout`.

I need the animation to not get cropped by Layout bounds but I can't use ViewOverlay because it's not API 8 compatible.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe **android:clipChildren="false"** should give means to achieve something alike.

Comment: Nope, it's not working. I used `setClipChildren` method to set it to `false` for every enclosing parent. The following are use in this order `ImageView` > `FrameLayout` > `LinearLayout` > `LinearLayout`. ClipChildren is set to false for each layout except the image itself. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, it's actually not an `ImageView`. It's called `Tile` and it extends `ButtonView`.

Comment: You may need to set `clipToPadding` in the parent to false too.

Comment: Android is opensource, why not just backport ViewOverlay then?

Comment: ivagarz, that did the trick. I was unaware that `setClipToPadding` would still take effect even though `setClipChildren` was already false. Please add your answer below and I'll award you the bounty. Thanks a ton! ^-^

Comment: There is backport of ViewOverlay here https://github.com/guerwan/TransitionsBackport

Comment: I already have a solution that doesn't require backporting but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if  the parents are already there inside your xml file, add android:clipChildren="false" to them inside the xml file instead of setting them in java.

Comment: `clipChildren` is not the issue. The `Tile` is set and generated in java. It's never declared in XML.

Comment: idk, does this library do any help on that? : [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/)

Comment: This solution is not correct and already was suggested harism above. Please do not upvote. Ivagarz gave the correct solution. No bounty should be awarded to this answer.

Comment: No, MDP, NineOldAndroids helps with things like animation event triggers that don't exist in API 8, but it doesn't look like it helps with anything like ViewOverlay